# HTML/CSS Why is the copyright sign not being interpreted properly?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, formatting

This thing has stumped me. I have inserted a copyright sign as text in my div. But on opening the HTML page in chrome Â© appears instead of just ©. I'm using Helvetica font. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Exactly how did you do that? (The right way is `&copy;` or `&#169;`)

Comment: The Unicode character *should* work unless your page is being served with some different character set.

Comment: You had a character encoding mismatch. Either you fixed it, or you avoided this symptom by using `&copy;`. Anyway, the question does not contain code and information for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `&copy;` instead of ©. This is the HTML code for that symbol.